# Find duplicate characters in a String and count the number of occurrences using Java

Tags: java

How can I find the number of occurrences of a character in a string?

**For example: The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog**.

Some example outputs are below,

```
'a' = 1
'o' = 4
'space' = 8
'.' = 1
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Is this a homework?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import java.io.*;
public class CountChar 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
      String ch;
      BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
      System.out.print("Enter the Statement:");
      ch=br.readLine();
      int count=0,len=0;
        do
        {  
          try
          {
          char name[]=ch.toCharArray();
              len=name.length;
              count=0;
              for(int j=0;j<len;j++)
               {
                  if((name[0]==name[j])&&((name[0]>=65&&name[0]<=91)||(name[0]>=97&&name[0]<=123))) 
                      count++;
               }
              if(count!=0)
                System.out.println(name[0]+" "+count+" Times");
              ch=ch.replace(""+name[0],"");          
          }
          catch(Exception ex){}
        }
        while(len!=1);
   }

}
```

> **Output**

```
Enter the Statement:asdf23123sfsdf

a 1 Times

s 3 Times

d 2 Times

f 3 Times
```

Answer (score 30):

You could use the following, provided String `s` is the string you want to process.

```
Map<Character,Integer> map = new HashMap<Character,Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
  char c = s.charAt(i);
  if (map.containsKey(c)) {
    int cnt = map.get(c);
    map.put(c, ++cnt);
  } else {
    map.put(c, 1);
  }
}
```

Note, it will count all of the chars, not only letters.

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov.. `Map` doesn't have a method `contains`

Comment: @RohitJain Sure, I was writing by memory. Corrected.

Comment: I tried to use this solution but I am getting: an item with the same key has already been already. Is this acceptable?

Comment: Kala J, hashmaps don't allow for duplicate keys. The second value should just replace the previous value. I like the simplicity of this solution.

Comment: What is the time complexity of this approach vs the 2 for loop approach described as below, which is good in terms of time and space complexity ?

Comment: @SaurabhOza, this approach is better because you only iterate through string chars once - O(n), whereas with 2 for loops you iterate n/2 times in average - O(n^2). However, you require a little bit more memory to store intermediate results.

Answer (score 16):

Java 8 way:

```
"The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog."
        .chars()
        .mapToObj(i -> (char) i)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Object::toString, Collectors.counting()));
```

Answer (score 10):

```
 void Findrepeter(){
    String s="mmababctamantlslmag";
    int distinct = 0 ;

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++) {

            if(s.charAt(i)==s.charAt(j))
            {
                distinct++;

            }
        }   
        System.out.println(s.charAt(i)+"--"+distinct);
        String d=String.valueOf(s.charAt(i)).trim();
        s=s.replaceAll(d,"");
        distinct = 0;

    }

}
```

Comment: Seems rather inefficient, consider using a `Map<String, Integer>` instead. Also you appear to have a typo in the name of the method

Comment: A note on why it's inefficient: The time complexity of this program is O(n^2) which is unacceptable for n(length of the string) too large.

Comment: I am Using str ="ved prakash sharma" as input but i'm not getting actual output  my output - v--1
d--1
p--1
a--4
s--2
 --2
h--2

Answer (score 7):

A better way would be to create a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) to store your count. That would be a `Map<Character, Integer>`

You need iterate over each character of your string, and check whether its an alphabet. You can use [`Character#isAlphabetic`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isAlphabetic%28int%29) method for that. If it is an `alphabet`, increase its count in the `Map`. If the character is not already in the `Map` then add it with a count of `1`.

**NOTE**: - **`Character.isAlphabetic`** method is new in **`Java 7`**. If you are using an older version, you should use [`Character#isLetter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter%28char%29)

```
    String str = "asdfasdfafk asd234asda";
    Map<Character, Integer> charMap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    char[] arr = str.toCharArray();

    for (char value: arr) {

       if (Character.isAlphabetic(value)) {
           if (charMap.containsKey(value)) {
               charMap.put(value, charMap.get(value) + 1);

           } else {
               charMap.put(value, 1);
           }
       }
    }

    System.out.println(charMap);
```

**OUTPUT**: -

```
{f=3, d=4, s=4, a=6, k=1}
```

Comment: Btw, there is no `isAlphabetic()` in `Character` =) At least in java 6. It should be `isLetter()` perhaps.

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov. Edited post to quote that. Thanks :)

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov. Haha. Yes, indeed, till Java folks have not stopped working :)

Answer (score 4):

If your string only contains alphabets then you can use some thing like this.

```
public class StringExample {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "abcdabghplhhnfl".toLowerCase();
    // create a integer array for 26 alphabets.
    // where index 0,1,2.. will be the container for frequency of a,b,c...
    Integer[] ar = new Integer[26];
    // fill the integer array with character frequency.
    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++) {
        int j = str.charAt(i) -'a';
        if(ar[j]==null) {
            ar[j]= 1;
        }else {
            ar[j]+= 1;
        }
    }   
    // print only those alphabets having frequency greater then 1.
    for(int i=0;i<ar.length;i++) {
        if(ar[i]!=null && ar[i]>1) {
            char c = (char) (97+i);
            System.out.println("'"+c+"' comes "+ar[i]+" times.");
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Output:**

```
 'a' comes 2 times.
 'b' comes 2 times.
 'h' comes 3 times.
 'l' comes 2 times.
```

Answer (score 4):

Finding the duplicates in a `String`:

### Example 1 : Using HashMap

```
public class a36 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "Gini Rani";
        fix(a);
    }//main
    public static void fix(String a ){
        Map<Character ,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i <a.length() ; i++ ) {
        char ch = a.charAt(i);
                map.put(ch , map.getOrDefault(ch,0) +1 );
        }//for

       List<Character> list = new ArrayList<>();
       Set<Map.Entry<Character ,Integer> > entrySet = map.entrySet();

       for (  Map.Entry<Character ,Integer> entry : entrySet) {
             list.add( entry.getKey()  ); 

             System.out.printf(  " %s : %d %n" ,  entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()           );
       }//for
       System.out.println("Duplicate elements => " + list);

    }//fix
}
```

### Example 2 : using Arrays.stream() in Java 8

```
public class a37 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String aa = "Protijayi Gini";
        String[] stringarray = aa.split("");

    Map<String , Long> map =  Arrays.stream(stringarray)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(c -> c , Collectors.counting()));
        map.forEach( (k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " : "+ v)        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the implementation without using any Collection and with complexity order of n. Although the accepted solution is good enough and does not use Collection as well but it seems, it is not taking care of special characters.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class DuplicateCharactersInString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String string = "check duplicate charcters in string";
        string = string.toLowerCase();
        char[] charAr = string.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(charAr);
        for (int i = 1; i < charAr.length;) {
            int count = recursiveMethod(charAr, i, 1);
            if (count > 1) {
                System.out.println("'" + charAr[i] + "' comes " + count + " times");
                i = i + count;
            } else
                i++;
        }
    }

    public static int recursiveMethod(char[] charAr, int i, int count) {
        if (ifEquals(charAr[i - 1], charAr[i])) {
            count = count + recursiveMethod(charAr, ++i, count);
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static boolean ifEquals(char a, char b) {
        return a == b;
    }
}
```

Output :

```
' ' comes 4 times
'a' comes 2 times
'c' comes 5 times
'e' comes 3 times
'h' comes 2 times
'i' comes 3 times
'n' comes 2 times
'r' comes 3 times
's' comes 2 times
't' comes 3 times
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class dublicate 
{
public static void main(String...a)
{
    System.out.print("Enter the String");
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    String st=sc.nextLine();
    int [] ar=new int[256];
    for(int i=0;i<st.length();i++)
    {
        ar[st.charAt(i)]=ar[st.charAt(i)]+1;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<256;i++)
    {
        char ch=(char)i;
        if(ar[i]>0)
        {
            if(ar[i]==1)
            {
                System.out.print(ch);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print(ch+""+ar[i]);
            }
        }
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use google guava `Multiset<String>`.

```
Multiset<String> wordsMultiset = HashMultiset.create();
wordsMultiset.addAll(words);
for(Multiset.Entry<E> entry:wordsMultiset.entrySet()){
     System.out.println(entry.getElement()+" - "+entry.getCount());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class HashMapDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Create HashMap object to Store Element as Key and Value 
        HashMap<Character,Integer> hm= new HashMap<Character,Integer>();
        //Enter Your String From Console
        System.out.println("Enter an String:");
        //Create Scanner Class Object From Retrive the element from console to our java application
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Store Data in an string format
        String s1=sc.nextLine();
        //find the length of an string and check that hashmap object contain the character or not by using 
        //containskey() if that map object contain element only one than count that value as one or if it contain more than one than increment value 

        for(int i=0;i<s1.length();i++){
            if(!hm.containsKey(s1.charAt(i))){
                hm.put(s1.charAt(i),(Integer)1);
            }//if
            else{
                hm.put(s1.charAt(i),hm.get(s1.charAt(i))+1);
            }//else

        }//for

        System.out.println("The Charecters are:"+hm);
    }//main
}//HashMapDemo
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    char Char;
    int count;
    String a = "Hi my name is Rahul";
    a = a.toLowerCase();
    for (Char = 'a'; Char <= 'z'; Char++) {
        count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
            if (a.charAt(i) == Char) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Number of occurences of " + Char + " is " + count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name="AnuvratAnuvra";
        char[] arr = name.toCharArray();
        HashMap<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

        for(char val:arr){          
            map.put(val,map.containsKey(val)?map.get(val)+1:1);         
        }

        for (Entry<Character, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            if(entry.getValue()>1){
            Character key = entry.getKey();
            Object value = entry.getValue();

            System.out.println(key + ":"+value);
            }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

class A {

```
public static void getDuplicates(String S) {
    int count = 0;
    String t = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < S.length() - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < S.length(); j++) {
            if (S.charAt(i) == S.charAt(j) && !t.contains(S.charAt(j) + "")) {
                t = t + S.charAt(i);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(t);
}
```

}

class B
public class B {

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    A.getDuplicates("mymgsgkkabcdyy");

}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you provide an explanation of your code and how it is different or better than other answers which have already been provided?

Answer (score 1):

Using [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/) `CharAdapter` and `CharBag`:

```
CharBag bag = 
    Strings.asChars("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.").toBag();

Assert.assertEquals(1, bag.occurrencesOf('a'));
Assert.assertEquals(4, bag.occurrencesOf('o'));
Assert.assertEquals(8, bag.occurrencesOf(' '));
Assert.assertEquals(1, bag.occurrencesOf('.'));
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve it by iterating over your `String` and using a `switch` to check each individual character, adding a counter whenever it finds a match. Ah, maybe some code will make it clearer:

**Main Application:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String test = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";

        int countA = 0, countO = 0, countSpace = 0, countDot = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < test.length(); i++) {
            switch (test.charAt(i)) {
                case 'a':
                case 'A': countA++; break;
                case 'o':
                case 'O': countO++; break;
                case ' ': countSpace++; break;
                case '.': countDot++; break;
            }
        }

        System.out.printf("%s%d%n%s%d%n%s%d%n%s%d", "A: ", countA, "O: ", countO, "Space: ", countSpace, "Dot: ", countDot);

    }
```

**Output:**

```
A: 1
O: 4
Space: 8
Dot: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways to find duplicates

```
public class WAP_PrintDuplicates {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String input = "iabccdeffghhijkkkl";

        findDuplicate1(input);
        findDuplicate2(input);
        findDuplicate3(input);

    }

    private static void findDuplicate3(String input) {

        HashMap<Character, Integer> hm = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length() - 1; i++) {
            int ch = input.charAt(i);
            if (hm.containsKey(input.charAt(i))) {
                int value = hm.get(input.charAt(i));
                hm.put(input.charAt(i), value + 1);
            } else {
                hm.put(input.charAt(i), 1);
            }
        }
        Set<Entry<Character, Integer>> entryObj = hm.entrySet();
        for (Entry<Character, Integer> entry : entryObj) {

            if (entry.getValue() > 1) {
                System.out.println("Duplicate: " + entry.getKey());
            }
        }

    }

    private static void findDuplicate2(String input) {

        int i = 0;

        for (int j = i + 1; j < input.length(); j++, i++) {

            if (input.charAt(i) == input.charAt(j)) {
                System.out.println("Duplicate is: " + input.charAt(i));
            }
        }

    }

    private static void findDuplicate1(String input) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {

            for (int j = i + 1; j < input.length(); j++) {

                if (input.charAt(i) == input.charAt(j)) {
                    System.out.println("Duplicate is: " + input.charAt(i));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
public class DuplicateCountChar{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner inputString = new Scanner(System.in);
        String token = inputString.nextLine();
        char[] ch = token.toCharArray();
        Map<Character, Integer> dupCountMap =  new HashMap<Character,Integer>();

        for (char c : ch) {
            if(dupCountMap.containsKey(c)) { 
                dupCountMap.put(c, dupCountMap.get(c)+1);
            }else {
                dupCountMap.put(c, 1);
            }
        }


        for (char c : ch) {
            System.out.println("Key = "+c+ "Value : "+dupCountMap.get(c));
        }

        Set<Character> keys = dupCountMap.keySet();
        for (Character character : keys) {
            System.out.println("Key = "+character+ " Value : " + dupCountMap.get(character));
        }

    }**
```

Answer (score 0):

In java... using for loop:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author MD SADDAM HUSSAIN */
public class Learn {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = sc.next();
        char process[] = input.toCharArray();
        boolean status = false;
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < process.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < process.length; j++) {

                if (i == j) {
                    continue;
                } else {
                    if (process[i] == process[j]) {
                        status = true;
                        index = i;
                        break;
                    } else {
                        status = false;

                    }
                }

            }
            if (status) {
                System.out.print("" + process[index]);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  public class StringCountwithOutHashMap {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Plz Enter Your String: ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s1 = sc.nextLine();
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < s1.length(); j++) {
            if (s1.charAt(i) == s1.charAt(j)) {
                count++;
            } 
        } 
        System.out.println(s1.charAt(i) + " --> " + count);
        String d = String.valueOf(s1.charAt(i)).trim();
        s1 = s1.replaceAll(d, "");
        count = 0;
    }}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CountH {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "Hi how are you";

        char charCount = 'h';
        int count = 0;

        input = input.toLowerCase();

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {

            if (input.charAt(i) == charCount) {
                count++;
            }

        }

        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DuplicateValue {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s = "hezzz";

        char []st=s.toCharArray();

        int count=0;

        Set<Character> ch=new HashSet<>();
        for(Character cg:st){
            if(ch.add(cg)==false){
                int occurrences = Collections.frequency(ch, cg);
                count+=occurrences;
                if(count>1){
                System.out.println(cg + ": This character exist more than one time");
                }
                else{
                System.out.println(cg);
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                       Map<Character,Integer> listMap = new HashMap<Character,Integer>();                         
                       Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
                       System.out.println("enter the string");
                       String name=in.nextLine().toString();
                       Integer value=0;
                       for(int i=0;i<name.length();i++){

                                     if(i==0){
                                                   listMap.put(name.charAt(0), 1);
                                     }
                                     else if(listMap.containsKey(name.charAt(i))){
                                                                value=listMap.get(name.charAt(i));
                                                                listMap.put(name.charAt(i), value+1);

                                     }else listMap.put(name.charAt(i),1);


                       }

                       System.out.println(listMap);
```

Comment: Please give an explanation why your example solves the question. This will make it much more valuable. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        String reverse1;
        String reverse2;
        int count = 0;
        while(n > 0)
        {
            String A = sc.next();
            String B = sc.next();
            reverse1 = new StringBuffer(A).reverse().toString();
            reverse2 = new StringBuffer(B).reverse().toString();
            if(!A.equals(reverse1))
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < A.length(); i++)
                {
                    for(int j = 0; j < A.length(); j++)
                    {
                        if(A.charAt(j) == A.charAt(i))
                        {
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                    if(count % 2 != 0)
                    {
                        A.replace(A.charAt(i),"");
                        count = 0;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(A);
            }
            n--;
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class list {

    public static String name(Character k){
        String s="the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
        int count=0;
        String l1="";
        String l="";
        List<Character> list=new ArrayList<Character>();
        for(int i1=0;i1<s.length();i1++){
            list.add(s.charAt(i1));
        }
        list.sort(null);
        for (Character character : list) {
            l+=character;
        }
        for (int i1=0;i1<l.length();i1++) {
            if((l.charAt(i1)==k)){
                count+=1;
                l1=l.charAt(i1)+" "+Integer.toString(count);
                if(k==' '){
                    l1="Space"+" "+Integer.toString(count);
                }
            }else{
                count=0;
            }
        }
        return l1;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String g = name('.');
        System.out.println(g);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use formatting tools to properly edit and format your question/answer.
Codes within sentences are to be formatted as `code` 
Very Important words to be **bold** , lesser important onces *Italic*
Also use lists if necessary

Answer (score 0):

**Simple and Easy way to find char occurrences >**

```
void findOccurrences() {
    String s = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
    Map<String, Integer> occurrences = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
    
    for (String ch : s.split("")) {
        Integer count = occurrences.get(ch);
        occurrences.put(ch, count == null ? 1 : count + 1);
    }
    System.out.println(occurrences);
}
```

This will print output as:

> {T=1, h=2, e=4,  =8, q=1, u=2, i=1, c=1, k=1, b=1, r=2, o=4, w=1, n=1, f=1, x=1, j=1, m=1, p=1, d=2, v=1, t=1, l=1, a=1, z=1, y=1, g=1, .=1}

Answer (score 0):

```
    String str = "anand";
    Map<Character, Integer> map
        = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

    // Converting string into a char array
    char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();

    for (char c : charArray) {

        if (map.containsKey(c)) {

            // If character is present increment count by 1
            map.put(c, map.get(c) + 1);
        }
        else {

          // If character is not present
          //putting this character into map with 1 as it's value.
            map.put(c, 1);
        }
    }

    for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry :
         map.entrySet()) {

            System.out.println(entry.getKey()
                               + " : "
                               + entry.getValue());
    }
```

> **Output**:
>
> a:2 n:2 d:1

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code snippet

```
import java.util.HashMap;
```

import java.util.Map;

public class CountDuplicateChar {

```
public static void main(String... strings) {
    withSortedString("aaaaabbcccccc");
    withUnSortedString("aaaaab bcc *@ccccf");
    withHashMap("bala");
}

private static void withHashMap(String inputString) {
    Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    char[] charArray = inputString.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0 ; i < charArray.length ; i++ ){
        if (map.containsKey(charArray[i])) {
            map.put(charArray[i],  map.get(charArray[i]) +1);
        } else {
            map.put(charArray[i], 1);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(map);
}

private static void withUnSortedString(String unSortedString) {
    int len = 0;
    do {
        char[] ch = unSortedString.toCharArray();
        if (ch.length ==0)
            break;
        int count = 0 ;
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < ch.length; i++) {
            if (ch[0] == ch[i]) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(ch[0] + " - " + count + "times");
        unSortedString = unSortedString.replace(""+ch[0],"");
    }while (len!=1);
}

private static void withSortedString(String s) {
    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++)
    {
        System.out.print(s.charAt(i)+""+(s.lastIndexOf(s.charAt(i))-s.indexOf(s.charAt(i))+1));
        i = s.lastIndexOf(s.charAt(i));
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Using **Java 8 streams** with **groupingBy()**

```
//way 1
String name = "anandha";
Map<Character,Long> map = name.chars()
                      .mapToObj(ch -> (char)ch)
                      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ch -> ch, Collectors.counting());
System.out.println(map);
```

using **LinkedHashmap**

```
//way2
String name = "anandha";
char[] charArray = name.toChararray();
Map<Character,Integer> map = new LinkedHashmap<>();

for(char ch: charArray)
{
    if(map.containsKey(ch))
    {
        map.put(ch,map.get(ch)+1);
    }else
    {
        map.put(ch,1)
    }
}

map.foreach((key,value)->{
   {
       System.out.println(key +" : "+ value);
   }
 });

//(OR) iterate map using the way above or below 
for(Map.Entry mp: map.entrySet())
{
    System.out.println(mp.getKey()+" : "+ mp.getValue());
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] array = "aabsbdcbdgratsbdbcfdgs".toCharArray();
        char[][] countArr = new char[array.length][2];
        int lastIndex = 0;
        for (char c : array) {
            int foundIndex = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < lastIndex; i++) {
                if (countArr[i][0] == c) {
                    foundIndex = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (foundIndex >= 0) {
                int a = countArr[foundIndex][1];
                countArr[foundIndex][1] = (char) ++a;
            } else {
                countArr[lastIndex][0] = c;
                countArr[lastIndex][1] = '1';
                lastIndex++;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < lastIndex; i++) {
            System.out.println(countArr[i][0] + " " + countArr[i][1]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
//sample Input
/*2
7
saska
toro
winn
toro
vanco
saska
toro
3
edddddd
edddddd
edddddd*/
//sample output
/*4
  1*/

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyTestWhere {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count, line;
        Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);
        count = sn.nextInt();
        sn.nextLine();          
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) { 
            line = sn.nextInt();
            sn.nextLine();
        //  String numArr[] = new String[line];
            ArrayList<String> Arr=new ArrayList<String>();
            String first = sn.nextLine();
            Arr.add(first);String f;
            for (int j = 1; j < line; j++) {
                f= sn.nextLine();
                for(int k=0;k<Arr.size();k++){
                    if(f.equalsIgnoreCase(Arr.get(k)))break;
                    else if(k== (Arr.size()-1)){Arr.add(f);}

                }
            }   

            System.out.println(Arr.size());

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post just code blocks, add some context around it. How does this solve the OP's issue? What does your code do? E.t.c

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    class Test
    { 

        static String s2="";
        int l;
        void countDuplicateCharacters(String Str)
        {
            String S=Str.toLowerCase();
            for(int i=0;i<S.length();i++)
            {
                int k=1;
                boolean value=  repeatedCheck(S.charAt(i));
                if(value==true)
                    continue;
                for(int j=i+1;j<S.length();j++)
                {


                    if(S.charAt(i)==S.charAt(j))
                    {   k++;

                    }

            }
                System.out.println("character  '" +S.charAt(i)+"' : "+k);

                s2=s2+S.charAt(i);
            }

        }

        boolean repeatedCheck(char ch)
        {
            l=s2.length();
            for (int i=0;i<l;i++)
            {
                if(s2.charAt(i)==ch)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

    }

    public class Duplicacy {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter any String");
            String s=sc.nextLine();
            Test t=new Test();
            t.countDuplicateCharacters(s);


        }}
```

Answer (score -2):

I solved this with 2 dimensional array.
Input: aaaabbbcdefggggh
Output:a4b3cdefg4h

```
int[][] arr = new int[10][2];
    String st = "aaaabbbcdefggggh";
    char[] stArr = st.toCharArray();
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < stArr.length; k++) {
        if (k == 0) {
            arr[i][j] = stArr[k];
            arr[i][j + 1] = 1;
        } else {
            if (arr[i][j] == stArr[k]) {
                arr[i][j + 1] = arr[i][j + 1] + 1;
            } else {
                arr[++i][j] = stArr[k];
                arr[i][j + 1] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.print(arr.length);
    String output = "";
    for (int m = 0; m < arr.length; m++) {
        if (arr[m][1] > 0) {
            String character = Character.toString((char) arr[m][0]);
            String cnt = arr[m][1] > 1 ? String.valueOf(arr[m][1]) : "";
            output = output + character + cnt;

        }
    }
    System.out.print(output);
```

Answer (score -3):

```
public static void findDuplicate(String letter)
{

    for(int i=0; i<letter.length();i++)
    {
        for( int j=i+1; j<letter.length();j++)
        {
            if(letter.charAt(i)==letter.charAt(j))
            {
                System.out.println(letter.charAt(j));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

findDuplicate("JAVA");

The OUTPUT is : A