# How to count and sort letters in a string

Tags: java

I want to sort the letters from user input and print out how many of each letter there is in the string from the user. This is what I have so far and i would like to know if this is the right way to do it. I am relatively new to java so please keep things s simple as possible. Ive made a few adjustments to my code upon the suggestions that I use loops instead of large amounts of if else constructs. This is what I have:

```
public class Assignment9
{
public static void main( String [] args )
{
    String user_string = Input.getString( "Please enter a string" );
    int length = user_string.length();
    int char_number = 1;
    int alphabet[] = new int[26];
    for( int repeats = 0 , repeats <= length , repeats++ )
    {
        char letter = user_string.charAt( char_number );
        char to_be_tested = Character.toLowerCase( letter );
        int subscript = 0;
        for(int letter_number = 97 , letter_number <= 122 , letter_number++ )
        {
            char tester = (char) letter_number;

            if( to_be_tested == tester )
            {
                alphabet[subscript]++;
                subscript++;
            }
        }
        char_number++;
    }
    display( alphabet );
}
public static void display( int alphabet[] )
{
    int letter = 65;
    for( int a = 0; a < alphabet.length; a++ )
    {
        char character = ( char )letter;
        System.out.println ( "letter " + character + " count is " + alphabet[a] );
        letter++;
    }
}
}
```

### I'm getting these errors

[Compilation errors](https://ideone.com/rlwDOH):

```
test.java:9: error: ';' expected
            for( int repeats = 0 , repeats <= length , repeats++ )
                                          ^
test.java:9: error: illegal start of expression
            for( int repeats = 0 , repeats <= length , repeats++ )
                                           ^
test.java:9: error: ';' expected
            for( int repeats = 0 , repeats <= length , repeats++ )
                                             ^
test.java:9: error: illegal start of expression
            for( int repeats = 0 , repeats <= length , repeats++ )
                                                     ^
test.java:9: error: ')' expected
            for( int repeats = 0 , repeats <= length , repeats++ )
                                                      ^
test.java:9: error: illegal start of expression
            for( int repeats = 0 , repeats <= length , repeats++ )
                                                                 ^
test.java:14: error: ';' expected
                    for(int letter_number = 97 , letter_number <= 122 , letter_number++ )
                                                              ^
test.java:14: error: illegal start of expression
                    for(int letter_number = 97 , letter_number <= 122 , letter_number++ )
                                                               ^
test.java:14: error: ';' expected
                    for(int letter_number = 97 , letter_number <= 122 , letter_number++ )
                                                                 ^
test.java:14: error: illegal start of expression
                    for(int letter_number = 97 , letter_number <= 122 , letter_number++ )
                                                                      ^
test.java:14: error: ')' expected
                    for(int letter_number = 97 , letter_number <= 122 , letter_number++ )
                                                                       ^
test.java:14: error: illegal start of expression
                    for(int letter_number = 97 , letter_number <= 122 , letter_number++ )
                                                                                        ^
12 errors
```

Comment: Has your instructor taught you what a loop is?  Could you try using one?  Also you should fix the syntax errors in your code, StackOverflow doesn't allow simple syntax questions like that.

Comment: Upvote just for awesome if/else statement

Comment: If by "awesome" you mean horrifying.

Comment: @markspace awesome effort for an horrifying code

Comment: Horrifying indeed. OP I recommend that you look at the usage of Arrays, your code is so bloated and what you're trying to do can easily be accomplished with prebuilt functions like `Array.indexOf(element)`. You could use that to match a letter in a word with the index of an array and increment that index for instance.

Comment: For your answer I would suggest to take a look at this: [How can I sort a List alphabetically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708698/how-can-i-sort-a-list-alphabetically) and this: [Find duplicate characters in a String and count the number of occurances using Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13119926/find-duplicate-characters-in-a-string-and-count-the-number-of-occurances-using-j). I hope those will help

Comment: Found my problem. They were incorrect syntax in for loop and incorrect operators.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simpler way to count letters, ignoring case:

```
final int[] chars = new int[26];
for (char c : value.toLowerCase().toCharArray()) {
  if ((c >= 'a') && (c<= 'z')) {
     chars[c - 'a']++;
  }
}
```

Demo: https://repl.it/CmYR/0

Comment: `value` is the String which you want to test, like `user_string`

Answer (score 2):

The thing is ***YOU*** are doing all of the work. What you need to do is make the ***COMPUTER*** work. All those printing statements take lots of copy pasting for no good reason. Hence using loops is a much more efficient way. And since you already know loops you could have come up with this solution-

```
import java.io.*;

public class experiments {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    //Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    int i,j;
    char chr;
    int len,count=0;
    System.out.println("Enter text-->");
    String str=br.readLine();
    str=str.toUpperCase();
    len=str.length();
    for(i='A';i<='Z';i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<len;j++)
        {
            chr=str.charAt(j);
            if(chr==i)count++;              
        }
        System.out.println((char)i+"-->"+count);
        count=0;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain how this one works. I would really like to use some of the keywords you used here in later programs.

Comment: The first thing is that we are taking a string input and converting it to uppercase(keep reading and u will understand why i did that :)... ).

Answer (score 1):

A simpler approach would be to use the map data structure. It stores (key, value) pairs. In your case the key would be the letter, and the value would be an integer representing the count. So when you encounter say, an 'a' you do `yourMap.get('a')` and increment the value paired with that key.

Here you can read about maps in java: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Answer (score 1):

I would much rather use a map here to store the counts of each of the letters:

```
Map<Character, Integer> letterMap = new HashMap<>();
String userString = Input.getString( "Please enter a string" );

for (int i=0; i < userString.length(); ++i) {
    char letter = userString.charAt(i);
    Integer value = letterMap.get(letter);

    letterMap.put(letter, value == null ? 1 : value.intValue() + 1);
}

for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : letterMap.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("Letter '" + entry.getKey() + "' appeared " + entry.getValue() + " times.");
}
```

As @Stephank pointed out, this solution will not print any summary stats for letters which do not appear at all in the input.  If you want to print stats for *all* letters, even if they do not appear, you could seed the map with the following code:

```
for (char letter = 'a'; letter <= 'z'; ++letter) {
    letterMap.put(letter, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 8 Streams

```
    String data = "some letters to count";

    Stream.of(data.split("(?!^)"))
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), TreeMap::new, Collectors.counting()))
          .forEach((key, value)->System.out.println(key+": "+value));
```

And here is the explanation:

1. First we split the data in one letter strings using a regular expression: `data.split("(?!^)")`; and we obtain an array of `String`'s.

   `0 = "s"
   1 = "o"
   2 = "m"
   3 = "e"
   4 = " "
   5 = "l"
   6 = "e"
   7 = "t"
   8 = "t"
   9 = "e"
   10 = "r"
   11 = "s"
   12 = " "
   13 = "t"
   14 = "o"
   15 = " "
   16 = "c"
   17 = "o"
   18 = "u"
   19 = "n"
   20 = "t"`
2. We create a `Stream` from the said array: `Stream.of(data.split("(?!^)"))`
3. We do all the sorting and counting in this step using a `groupingBy` `Collector` and passing a `TreeMap` (a `SortedMap` implementation that will keep `MapEntry`'s sorted by key): `.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), TreeMap::new, Collectors.counting()))`.

   The result of this step is a sorted `TreeMap` with distinct single character `String`'s as keys and the count of this character as value.

   `0 = {TreeMap$Entry@755} " " -> "3"
   1 = {TreeMap$Entry@756} "c" -> "1"
   2 = {TreeMap$Entry@757} "e" -> "3"
   3 = {TreeMap$Entry@758} "l" -> "1"
   4 = {TreeMap$Entry@759} "m" -> "1"
   5 = {TreeMap$Entry@760} "n" -> "1"
   6 = {TreeMap$Entry@761} "o" -> "3"
   7 = {TreeMap$Entry@762} "r" -> "1"
   8 = {TreeMap$Entry@763} "s" -> "2"
   9 = {TreeMap$Entry@764} "t" -> "4"
   10 = {TreeMap$Entry@765} "u" -> "1"`
4. Finally we print the result: `.forEach((key, value)->System.out.println(key+": "+value));`