# How to add String to Set that characters doesn't repeat

Tags: java, set

I am new in Sets in Java. I have a problem that I don't know how to do this:
I need to add Strings to my Set that characters doesn't reapet. 
For example string "ABC" would be add to my Set, but string "ABCC" wouldn't be add because contains double "C".

```
        import java.util.HashSet;
```

import java.util.Set;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<String> napisy = new HashSet<>();

}
```

}

Comment: So you need to write a method that checks whether a string has duplicate characters or not. Have you tried anything? A Set<String> won't do that for you.

Comment: There are plenty of ways to solve this problem, feels like you've got to do it urself and ask us if you have any troubles. We can't do it for you. And as far as I can see, none of the current answers does what you are after.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find duplicate characters in a String and count the number of occurances using Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13119926/find-duplicate-characters-in-a-string-and-count-the-number-of-occurances-using-j)

Answer (score 1):

First try checking if the `String` has duplicates, and if not, then add it to the `Set`

```
Set<String> s = new HashSet<>();
String a = "Abc";
if(checkUnique(a)){
    s.add(a);
}
```

And the implementation of `checkUnique`

```
public static boolean checkUnique(String a){
    Set<Character> set = new HashSet<>();
    for(char c : a.toCharArray()){
        if(set.contains(c))
            return false;
        set.add(c);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Why not just return as soon as you found a duplicate?

Comment: IMHO, we shouldn't be doing other's HW for them.

Comment: @JBNizet fixed that. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @EanV so what should be my response to such questions ? I was just trying to help.

Comment: Don't use a List to call contains(). That has O(n) complexity, which is the same as String.indexOf() in the first place, making the list basically useless. A HashSet is O(1).

Comment: @Shashwat my strategy is to wait for the OP to at least try something by him/herself, rather than doing his/her homework.

Comment: As @JBNizet said, I'd wait for them to try something. Plus, `set.add` returns a boolean which u can check to see if the item was added and you don't need to do an extra `contains`.

Answer (score 1):

A possible way would be to iterate on each String and for each one of them you iterate on each char of them.
In this inner loop, you could use a `Set` that stores each encountered character for the current `String` and so as soon as a character to add is already in the Set, you stop iterating and you don't add the String. Otherwise, you add the `String`.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class SetWithNotCharDuplicated {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> inputStrings = Arrays.asList("ABC", "ABCC", "ABD", "AABD");
        Set<String> values = findStringsWithNoDupplicatedCharInsideIt(inputStrings);
        System.out.println(values);
    }

    private static Set<String> findStringsWithNoDupplicatedCharInsideIt(List<String> inputStrings) {
        Set<String> values = new HashSet<>();

        for (String string : inputStrings) {
            Set<Character> encounteredChars = new HashSet<Character>();

            boolean mustAdd = true;

            for (char c : string.toCharArray()) {

                // we skip the current String if already contained
                if (encounteredChars.contains(c)) {
                    mustAdd = false;
                    break;
                }
                encounteredChars.add(c);
            }

            if (mustAdd) {
                values.add(string);
            }
        }
        return values;
    }
}
```

Output :

> [ABC, ABD]

Comment: You don't need a Map. All you need is a Set to know if a character is in the string or not.

Comment: You are right, it is a not required code. My bad. I updated.

Answer (score 1):

I think the implementation below should be the correct and fast answer to above question.

consider a string str="abdg@d@aa%6%" 
This string should not be added to the set as it contains (3-times-a,2-times@ and 2-times% )

```
Step 1) First of all sort the string in ascending or descending order on the basis of ascii value of its character. 

Step 2)I don't know the ascii value of @ and % but whatever may be the ascii value the string will convert into a new string where similar character will be one after the other.
e.g. ascendingstr="6aaabddg@@%%" 

Step 3) Now one could simply iterate through the string checking whether are two aside character are same or not if yes then don't add it to set and if no then add it.
```

Moreover this implementation could work on more than 26 characters of English alphabet supported by ascii.

Answer (score 0):

```
for str in ... {
    bool repeated = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < str.length(); ++j) {
            if(str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(j)) {
                repeated = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (repeated) break;
    }

    if (repeated) // this str should not be added
    else napisy.add(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to do so first check whether string which is to be added contains repeated character or not if it Does't then only add it to the SET

below is the coding of a function which tells whether string contains double character or not.  If it returns true then string does not contains repeated characters.

```
boolean check(String str)
{
int frequ[]=new int[26];
for(int i=0;i<26;i++)
frequ[i]=0;
for(char ch='A';ch<'Z';ch++)
{
int fc=0;
for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
{
char c=str.charAt(i);
if(c==ch)
fc++;
}
frequ[(int)ch-65]=fc;
}

//not frequ array has frequency of all characters in string

for(int i=0;i<26;i++)
{
if(frequ[i]>1)//occuring more then 1
return false;
}
return true;
}
```

Comment: Your code only works for 26 characters, and is extremely inefficient: it makes 26 passes on the whole string, and computes the frequency of every character just to check if one of them is repeated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below simplified code (uses streams) to check the input for unique chars and then only add to the `set` object.

```
Set<String> napisy = new HashSet<>();
String input = "ABC";

//Check if input is unique chars & then only add to Set
// if the length of chara stream is not same as input, then chars are repeated
if((input.chars().mapToObj(i->(char)i)).distinct().count() == input.length()) {
    napisy.add(input);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can check if you have some duplicate letters in your string

```
public static boolean isUniqueChars(String str) {
    if (str.length() > 256) {
        return false;
    }
    int checker = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        int val = str.charAt(i) - 'a';
        if ((checker & (1 << val)) > 0) return false;
        checker |= (1 << val);
    }
    return true;
}
```

and then add it to the set if true

something like

```
boolean isUnique = isUniqueChars ( yourString);
if (isUnique)
yourSet.add(yourString);
```

EDIT : due to this line  `if (str.length() > 256)`  this implementation works for ASCII characters only

Comment: Do you really think there are only 256 possible characters?

Comment: why downvote ? I should have mentioned that its for ascii table

Comment: It doesn't even work for ASCII. Just try it wth `new String(new char[] {0, 0});`.

Answer (score -1):

Use add() method to add characters of a string in a set. add() method only adds elements if they are non-repeating. If they are repeating, it returns false.

Following code is to check if a string has repeated characters or not.

```
public static void main(String args[]) { 
  String s="ABBC";


  Set<Character> set = new HashSet<Character>();
  try {
     for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if(!set.add(s.charAt(i))){
             System.out.println("repeated");
             return;
        }
     }
      System.out.println("non repeated");

  }
  catch(Exception e) {}

  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Another Solution:

```
String a = "ABCC";

    char[] dizi = a.toCharArray();
    List<Character> array = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Character c : dizi) {
        array.add(c);
    }
    Set<Character> set = new HashSet<>(array);
```

Comment: Edit: the downvoters must explain the downvote reason.