# Using Java+regex, I want to find repeating characters in a string and replace that substring(s) with character found and # of times it was found

Tags: java, regex

sample

```
String str = "fghhhhjkjkljhdd"
```

i need to transform it into output string "fgh4jkjkljhd2"

I have the following code but the problem here is that i only get a single occurence matched - "hhhh". I'm still missing "dd".
Once this problem is solved i can think about how to assign matches to a string(s) and count characters there, but for now i 'm not able to get multiple matches. Any pointers are appreciated.

```
    String str = "fghhhhjkjkljhdd";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w)\\1+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    if (m.find()) System.out.println(m.group());
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13119926/find-duplicate-characters-in-a-string-and-count-the-number-of-occurances-using-j

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may wrap the quantified backreference with a capturing group to be able to access this value later, and use a `Matcher#appendReplacement` to actually modify the matches inside the string:

```
String text = "fghhhhjkjkljhdd";
String regex = "(\\w)(\\1+)";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = r.matcher(text);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(sb, m.group(1) + (m.group(2).length()+1));
}
m.appendTail(sb);
System.out.println(sb); // => fgh4jkjkljhd2
```

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/MCkEMq).

Comment: Thank you!. I was far from this solution on my own. First, i didn't fully understand the way regex works in group(2) here "(\\w)(\\1+)".

Comment: `(\\w)(\\1+)` contains 2 capturing groups, `(\\w)` is Group 1, `(\\1+)` is Group 2. Group 1 matches the first word char, and the 2nd matches one or more same chars as captured in Group 1.

Comment: Second, i should've been more careful reading Javadoc on Matcher#appendReplacement method. Thank you again!                          
I'm still to wrap my head around the solution from @Serhii, but i see it get the job done as well.

Comment: @Emil: Serhii's code will work as `(.)(\1+)` regex with my code. If you need to only replace word chars, you would use a regex approach. If you need to only make these replacements in a string that only consists of word chars, you will need to use `"\\G(\\w)(\\1+)(?=\\w*$)"` regex. Regex is better when you need to only match specific type of chars, and simple loop can be used when you do not care what the chars are.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it also with a simple loop

```
    String str = "fghhhhjkjkkljhdd";
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(String.valueOf(str.charAt(0)));
    char lastChar = str.charAt(0);
    int counter = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) == lastChar) {
            counter++;
        } else {
            lastChar = str.charAt(i);
            if (counter != 1) sb.append(counter);
            sb.append(lastChar);
            counter = 1;
        }
    }
    if(counter != 1) sb.append(counter);
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
    //fgh4jkjk2ljhd2
```